# Tags that belongs to other site

Tags: discussion, tags

There are tags which have a site dedicated for them. For example if I ask a question about game development (and tag it [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development)), I am advised to move it [to game-dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Then why that tag exists in Stack Overflow. Doesn't it mean [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) questions are allowed/welcome here?

I see some questions are answered there itself and some are to be moved to game-dev.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here? Are you asking for clarification on what belongs where? Or is this a feature request?

Comment: How to determine which site the question belongs to.ex:after what "limit" a game-development question would be closed in stackoverflow.com.Or should I better directly ask the question in game-dev? What I'm asking is why there is a "shared" tag ?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109552/should-game-development-tag-be-retired-since-we-have-gamedev-se-now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-development/info) of [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) gives a pretty nice summary of which questions belong where:

> Most questions that are unambiguously about programming problems specific to game development (as opposed to problems that happened to arise during game development but which may apply equally in most software) may be better suited for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, a site based on the same technology as StackOverflow but dedicated to game development questions (not only programming, but art, design, audio, business, etc).

In other words: if it's a programming question that *happens to occur* while you're developing a game, then it belongs on SO. If it's *specific to game development* (i.e. a similar question will not come up in non-game development), then gamedev is more appropriate. If the question is about *any aspect of game development* **except** programming, then it *clearly* belongs to gamedev.